# Inserting multiple inputs to MYSQL using PHP and html form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to read the columns and rows entered in the html form to be inserted into MYSQL database using php.

It is giving me the following error:

> Undefined index: maintenance  on line 28
>
> Undefined index: outages
>
> Undefined index: morningcheck
>
> Undefined offset: 1

Please advise as to how to make this work.

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

/*Open the connection to our database use the info from the config file.*/   
 
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_POST['add'])) {      
    foreach($_POST['address'] as $k => $address) {
        $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $address);
        $morningcheck = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['morningcheck'][$k]);
        $outages = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['outages'][$k]);
        $maintenance = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['maintenance'][$k]);
        $sql="INSERT INTO demo ( address,morningcheck, outages,  maintenance) VALUES ('$address','$morningcheck','$outages','$maintenance')";  
        if (!mysqli_query($link,$sql)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));   }       
    }}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Here is the html form:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">

<style>
td{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<input type="hidden" name="formID" value= "demo" />

<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <br>
    <b>Email Address </><input type="text" name="address[]"  />
    <input type="checkbox" name="morningcheck[]" value="morningcheck"> Morning Checks 
    <input type="checkbox" name="outages[]" value="outages"> Outages
    <input type="checkbox" name="maintenance[]" value="maintenance"> Maintenance<br>
    <br>
    </td>
</tr>
<table>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <br>
    <b>Email Address </><input type="text" name="address[]" placeholder= "Email address 1"  />
    <input type="checkbox" name="morningcheck[]" value="morningcheck"> Morning Checks
    <input type="checkbox" name="outages[]" value="outages"> Outages
    <input type="checkbox" name="maintenance[]" value="maintenance"> Maintenance<br>
    <br>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>


<br>
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="add"/>
<input type="submit" value="Unsubscribe" name="delete"/>


</form>'
```

Comment: in procedural code, never execute a query inside a loop. Either build the query inside the loop and execute it once, afterwards, or switch to PDO and use its special powers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there is an error being thrown because the variable is not present if it is not selected in the form, so you need to test for the variable when putting it into the sql like this

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])) {      
foreach($_POST['address'] as $k => $address) {
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $address);
    $morningcheck =(isset($_POST['morningcheck'][$k]))? mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['morningcheck'][$k]):NULL;
    $outages = (isset($_POST['outages'][$k]))?mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['outages'][$k]):NULL;
    $maintenance = (isset($_POST['maintenance'][$k]))?mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['maintenance'][$k]):NULL;
    $sql="INSERT INTO demo ( address,morningcheck, outages,  maintenance) VALUES ('$address','$morningcheck','$outages','$maintenance')";  
    if (!mysqli_query($link,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));   }
```

}}

What this is saying is, if the variable is set (The bit in the brackets) execute assigning the vaiable the bit before the ':'if not set it as null

Good luck

Keith

Comment: Keith: it is not adding anything to the database for some reason. Please advise.

Comment: No worries, glad to help

Comment: the database is not getting updated as it should. When I select outages in the first row and maintenance in the second, it adds both the outages and maintenance as part of the first row and not for teh second row. Please help

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want you should change your HTML like this :

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <br>
    <b>Email Address </><input type="text" name="Example[][address]" placeholder= "Email address 1"  />
    <input type="checkbox" name="Example[][morningcheck]" value="morningcheck"> Morning Checks
    <input type="checkbox" name="Example[][outages]" value="outages"> Outages
    <input type="checkbox" name="Example[][maintenance]" value="maintenance"> Maintenance<br>
    <br>
```

This way server side you can retrieve the data like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["Example"]){
  foreach($_POST["Example"] as $example){
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $example['address']);
    $morningcheck = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $example['morningcheck']);
    $outages = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $example['outages']);
    $maintenance = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $example['maintenance']);
    $sql="INSERT INTO demo ( address,morningcheck, outages,  maintenance) VALUES ('$address','$morningcheck','$outages','$maintenance')";
    if (!mysqli_query($link,$sql))die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
  }
}
```

Comment: You would still get the same issue if a check box is not checked though wouldnt you? The actual problem is that if the variables that are being  inserted are not present in the posted form you need a way of verifying the presence of the variable and assigning a null value (or other value) to make the query work.

Comment: You're right, you just need to check if the variable is set before using it

Comment: it is not adding anything to the database for some reason. Please advise

Comment: Print the query on the screen to check what you're trying to execute, and then print the error from mysql